# Exclude inherited class from serialized XSD schema

Tags: c#, xsd.exe

I am using MvvmCross to develop an editor for some XML data, and I'm using `System.Xml.Serialization` attributes to annotate my `MvxViewModel`s so model data can be easily saved to and loaded from XML.

Here's a class from my codebase as an example:

```cs
using System.Xml.Serialization;

using MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels;

namespace MyApp.Editor.Core.ViewModels
{
    [XmlType(Namespace = Constants.XML_SCHEMA_NS, TypeName = "CanvasExamChoice")]
    public class ChoiceViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        bool _correct;
        [XmlAttribute(Namespace = Constants.XML_SCHEMA_NS, AttributeName = "correct")]
        public bool Correct
        {
            get { return _correct; }
            set { SetProperty<bool>(ref _correct, value); }
        }
        string _text;
        [XmlText(typeof(string))]
        public string Text
        {
            get { return _text; }
            set { SetProperty<string>(ref _text, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my compiled DLL through xsd.exe to generate the schema, however, `xsd` generates these "empty" classes in the schema because `ChoiceViewModel` and the rest of my code are children of `MvxViewModel`, which is a child of `MvxNavigatingObject`, and etc etc:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://my.org/namespace" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://my.org/namespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="CanvasExamChoices">
        <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
            <xs:extension base="tns:MvxViewModel">
                <xs:attribute name="shuffle" type="xs:boolean" use="required" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="MvxViewModel" abstract="true">
        <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
            <xs:extension base="tns:MvxNavigatingObject" />
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="MvxNavigatingObject" abstract="true">
        <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
            <xs:extension base="tns:MvxNotifyPropertyChanged" />
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="MvxNotifyPropertyChanged" abstract="true">
        <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
            <xs:extension base="tns:MvxMainThreadDispatchingObject" />
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="MvxMainThreadDispatchingObject" abstract="true" />
    <xs:complexType name="CanvasExamChoice" mixed="true">
        <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
            <xs:extension base="tns:MvxViewModel">
                <xs:attribute name="correct" type="xs:boolean" use="required" />
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <!-- Other types and root element are here -->
</xs:schema>
```

`System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute` can only be used on public fields/properties, though. On top of that, it doesn't look like I can use `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSchemaProviderAttribute` because MvvmCross's targets (Probably the Windows 8 target) seem to make the `System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet` class unavailable.

How do I get `xsd` to ignore the MvvmCross classes, since they have absolutely no bearing on the XML data structure?

Comment: Maybe you should create a separate, simpler, Model and use it in the ViewModel

Comment: @Tony That ended up being the method I went with. Could you make this into a proper answer so I can mark the question as answered and give you due credit?

I did a bunch more research and there really doesn't seem to be a way to accomplish this with just annotations and `xsd.exe`.